# Como obtener un array de sql y manipularlo con js

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Me gustaría saber como puedo obtener el campo "filename" de mi base de datos para posteriormente utilizarlo en mi contante canciones que es un array el cual tiene la lista de reproducción.
Entonces en pocas palabras.
¿Hay forma de poder pasar un array de una base de datos para que sea un dato manipulable para js?
No me cierro a ningún tipo de solución, Gracias.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Este es el reproductor en el que estoy trabajando

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Esta es la tabla de la que quiero sacar la información y se llama "file"

```
const canciones = [
  "cancion1.mp3",
  "cancion2.mp3",
  "cancion3.mp3",
  "cancion4.mp3",
  "cancion5.mp3",
  "cancion6.mp3",
  "cancion7.mp3",
  "cancion8.mp3",
  "cancion9.mp3",
  "cancion10.mp3",
  ]
```

y este es mi array pero como se pueden dar cuenta es estático y lo que quiero es que vaya variando dependiendo de los datos que haya en la tabla.
Si necesitan algo mas no duden en pedirlo.

Comment: con que backend estas trabajando?
Tienes que hacer que tu backend te devuelva esa lista, un getAll puede servirte. Ya luego con js la recorres y te quedas con un nuevo arreglo que contenga la propiedad que necesitas.

Comment: estoy trabando con ajax, lo que quiero no es tan especifico si no que es mas general ya que requiero TODOS los campos de la tabla file

Comment: Danos un poco más de contexto, algo de código con el que hayas intentado y qué parte del mismo no te funciona. Visita [esta sección](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que conozcas las pautas y hacer que tu pregunta sea aceptada en la comunidad.

Comment: La pregunta no es clara. Si lo que quieres es comunicar entre el cliente y el servidor lo mejor es usar Ajax.